# Multibinding unset value

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, multibinding

I've got a PdfViewerView.xaml (`UserControl`) which contains a control named "PdfViewerCtrl".
Now I got a `ListBox` with a context menu and if the user clicks the context menuitem an event with multibinding triggers:

```
<ContextMenu>
              <MenuItem Header="Löschen"/>
              <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 <i:EventTrigger
                                    EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                        Command="{Binding DeleteAnnotationCmd}">
                       <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConv}">
                             <Binding ElementName="PdfUserCtrl" Path="PdfViewerCtrl" />
                             <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="PdfViewerCtrl" />
                          </MultiBinding>
                       </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                 </i:EventTrigger>
              </i:Interaction.Triggers>
           </ContextMenu>
```

I'm trying to pass the `PdfViewerCtrl` (which I mentioned at the beginning) as parameter but it's always `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

As you can see I tried two ways of binding to the `PdfViewerCtrl` but both won't work.

Comment: The problem is because `ContextMenu` is a `PopUp`. It has different `NameScope` to its onwer, and also is not part of visual tree of its onwer. So `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` will both fail to solve the source.

Comment: Do you know any solution how to pass the "owner" of the contextmenu? its a listbox

Comment: `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` should contain the owner element after it was opened. You could try `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}" Path="PlacementTarget" />`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Tag` property to the `PdfViewerCtrl` using the `x:Reference` markup extension and then bind to the `Tag` property of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<ContextMenu Tag="{x:Reference PdfViewerCtrl}">
    <MenuItem Header="Löschen"/>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DeleteAnnotationCmd}">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConv}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}" Path="Tag" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: One more question, maybe you can help me too. I also tried to pass the listbox (the "parent" of the ContextMenu). What is the smartest way to do that?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. I would be happy to help you if I can.